# Java Beans: Getting value of bean property which has application scope into the scriplets?

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans, scriptlet

How to get value of bean property which has application scope into the scriplets?
Here `tv1` is the bean instance and `getNum()` returns an integer.

```
    <%
       for(int j=1; j<=${applicationScope.tv1.getNum()}; j++) {
           //code to execute
       }
     %>
```

This is not working..
EL works outside scriplets but not inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

Type is the type of tv1 bean

```
<%  
       Type tv1 = (Type)application.getAttribute("tv1");
       //OR
       Type tv1 = (Type)servletContext.getAttribute("tv1");
       for(int j=1; j<=tv1.getNum(); j++) {
           //code to execute
       }
%>
```